# KafkaListener can not receive message after Spring boot application restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, spring-kafka

I have an Springboot with Kafka application, and my Kafka cluster start with docker compose file. However, if Kafka cluster keep start, but Spring boot application restart, it can not receive any message (The function work normal)

Properties file:

```
server.port=18080
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:29092,localhost:39092
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.main.banner-mode=off

config.kafka.topic1=quickstart-events
config.kafka.retry.delay=10000
config.kafka.processing.interval=10000
config.kafka.producer.interval=10000
config.kafka.consumer.groupId=quickstart-events-group-id
```

KafkaConfiguration.java

```
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Serializer<Student> defaultJsonSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topicExample(@Value("${config.kafka.topic1}") String topic, @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}") String servers) {
        int length = servers.split(",").length;
        return TopicBuilder.name(topic)
                .partitions(length)
                .replicas(1)
                .build();
    }

}
```

StudentListener.java

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class StudentListener extends AbstractBaseKafkaListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private final String listenerId = "kafka_consumerListener";

    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public StudentListener(List<MessageHandler> messageHandlers, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry) {
        super(messageHandlers);
        this.kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = {"${config.kafka.topic1}"}, groupId = "${config.kafka.consumer.groupId}", autoStartup = "true")
    public void onMessage(String message, MessageHeaders headers, Acknowledgment ack) {
        super.onMessage(message, headers, ack);
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        log.info("Application ready, start KafkaListener {}", listenerId);
        //kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer(listenerId).start();
    }
}
```

Part of docker-compose.yml

```
  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - 39092:39092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      zk-kafka-network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6
```

Comment: 1) You don't need multiple brokers or Zookeeper servers 2) What do you mean "keep start"?

Comment: "Keep start" here means, during I stop and start Springboot application, I don't make kafka server down, keep it running, sorry for typo @OneCricketeer

Comment: I still don't understand. Spring doesn't control the lifecycle of your Kafka containers. You can restart your Spring app as many times as you want and it won't affect Kafka. What exactly is the error you're getting? Do you understand how consumer groups and `auto.offset.reset` works? It's unclear what's producing data for your code to actually consume

Comment: I meet the problem is, the first time I start the application, it can send message and receive message from Kafka. However, if I restart the spring application, it would still send message but has possibility not receive messages. Do you think I have wrong config? @OneCricketeer

Comment: If you restart the app with the same consumer group, then it wont re-consume previous data since Kafka maintains the consumer position. If there is no new data between restarts, then nothing will be consumed. Is that what you mean? Regarding the config - like I said, you don't really need multiple broker or zookeeepers for local testing

Comment: What I mean is. Step 1, I start the Kafka server. Step 2, I start the Spring app. And it works well, it can send message and receive message. Step 3, I restart the Spring APP, and it can send message, but can not receive message. Step 4, I restart the Spring App again, it has possible to receive message suddenly. I have not change any config. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Like I said, Kafka maintains the position of the consumer. If there's no data and everything is consumed, you'll not see it consume until there is data... You've not shown any producer code here, so it's unclear what is creating any data or why you'd need to consume from the same topic that the local app is producing to (if your Spring app does have a producer)

Answer (score 1):

By setting these properties and not committing any offset manually, the app will seek to the end of the topic every time it is started.

```
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=MANUAL_IMMEDIATE
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=latest
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
```

There will be no data to consume at the end of the topic until the consumer is running while a producer sends data. So, if a consumer isn't working the way you expect, look at the producer application first.

If the producer is working, then you can use GetOffsetShell tool to verify the offsets in the topic are increasing.

If the offsets **are** increasing and you want to capture all events, not only the latest, set

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

And ack the message

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"${config.kafka.topic1}"}, groupId = "${config.kafka.consumer.groupId}", autoStartup = "true")
public void onMessage(String message, MessageHeaders headers, Acknowledgment ack) {
    super.onMessage(message, headers, ack);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge(); 
}
```

If the consumer restarts, the consumer group is at the end of the topic, **and the offsets are not increasing**, then there's no data to consume, but the app will continue to poll the broker.